# How to view Mozilla Firefox source code within Firefox without an internet connection?

Tags: firefox, browser, css, open-source, source-code

When connected to the internet, Mozilla provides easy access to all source code for Firefox here:
https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/

When not connected to the internet, what internal URL's can be used to view Firefox's source code?

***Example:***

Viewing Firefox's resources using internal URL's is easy.  For example, to view the More menu icon, you can enter [chrome://global/skin/icons/more.svg](http://chrome://global/skin/icons/more.svg) into Firefox's address bar.

But what internal URL would be used to access a Firefox CSS file, such as this file:
https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/themes/shared/tabs.inc.css

Comment: You don’t; An online resource requires internet access;  Mozilla releases the source for Firefox [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Source_Code/Downloading_Source_Archives)

Comment: How to Create userChrome.css in Firefox https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html This page might be an older version of Firefox, however it works. Firefox always had the name Chrome, it is not Google's, by the way. Peace

Comment: why should Mozilla distribute Firefox along with the source code? Almost no one would do that. If one wants the source code they'll clone from the repo or download from the internet. Otherwise the installed application contains just compiled binaries

Comment: @phuclv Incorrect. If you study the Firefox source code and build process, you'll understand essentials like how Firefox retrieves resources from omni.ja.  While studying the code, you'll also see how Firefox interprets CSS.  If you choose to study the source code and build process, you'll quickly learn that your statement claiming "the installed application contains just compiled binaries" is incorrect.  Note also that I'm looking for the internal URL to access CSS code, not C++ code.